# Copy Blob in Azure Blob Storage using Java v12 SDK

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

My Application is in a Kubernetes cluster and I'm using [Java v12 SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#azure-storage-blob-client-library-for-java) to interact with the Blob Storage. To authorize against Blob Storage I'm using Managed Identities.

My application needs to copy blobs within one container. I haven't found any particular [recommendations or examples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#examples) of how SDK should be used to do the copy.

I figured that the following approach works when I'm working with the emulator

```
copyBlobClient.copyFromUrl(sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl());
```

However, when this gets executed in the cluster I get the following error

```
<Error>
   <Code>CannotVerifyCopySource</Code>
   <Message>The specified resource does not exist. RequestId: __ Time: __ </Message>
</Error>
```

Message says "resource does not exist" but the blob is clearly there. My container has private access, though.

Now when I change the public access level to "Blob(anonymous read access for blobs only)" everything works as excepted. However, public access not acceptable to me.

**Main question - what are the right ways to implement copy blob using Java v12 SDK.**

What I could miss or misconfigured in my situation?

And the last is the error message itself. There is a part which says "CannotVerifyCopySource" which kind of helps you understand that there is something with access, but the message part is clearly misleading. Shouldn't it be more explicit about the error?

Comment: Please create a sas token for the source blob :https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/681a791bf39aa5e715ba82c889417786fd9918cc/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/src/samples/java/com/azure/storage/blob/specialized/BlobClientBaseJavaDocCodeSnippets.java#L522.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: @JimXu Thank you for your comments and answer. I'm going to try it as soon as I have the possibility, will provide feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to  use Azure JAVA SDK to copy blob with Azure MSI, please refer to the following details

- **Copy blobs between storage accounts**

If you copy blobs between storage accounts with Azure MSI. We should do the following actions

1. Assign Azure `Storage Blob Data Reader` to the MSI in the source container
2. Assign Azure `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to the MSI in the dest container. Besides when we copy blob, we need write permissions to write content to blob
3. Generate SAS token for the blob. If the souce blob is public, we can directly use source blob URL without sas token.

For example

```
 try {
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                    .endpoint("https://<>.blob.core.windows.net/" )
                    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                    .buildClient();
            // get User Delegation Key
            OffsetDateTime delegationKeyStartTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
            OffsetDateTime delegationKeyExpiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(7);
            UserDelegationKey key =blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(delegationKeyStartTime,delegationKeyExpiryTime);

            BlobContainerClient sourceContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("test");
            BlobClient sourceBlob = sourceContainerClient.getBlobClient("test.mp3");
            // generate sas token
            OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1);
            BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true);

            BlobServiceSasSignatureValues myValues = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, permission)
                    .setStartTime(OffsetDateTime.now());
            String sas =sourceBlob.generateUserDelegationSas(myValues,key);

            // copy
            BlobServiceClient desServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                    .endpoint("https://<>.blob.core.windows.net/" )
                    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                    .buildClient();
            BlobContainerClient desContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("test");
            String res =desContainerClient.getBlobClient("test.mp3")
                    .copyFromUrl(sourceBlob.getBlobUrl()+"?"+sas);
            System.out.println(res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image]

- **Copy in the same account**

If you copy blobs in the same storage account with Azure MSI, I suggest you assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to the MSI in the storage account. Then we can do copy action with the method `copyFromUrl`.

For example

a. Assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to the MSI at the account level

b. code

```
  try {
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                    .endpoint("https://<>.blob.core.windows.net/" )
                    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                    .buildClient();

            BlobContainerClient sourceContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("test");
            BlobClient sourceBlob = sourceContainerClient.getBlobClient("test.mp3");

            BlobContainerClient desContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("output");
            String res =desContainerClient.getBlobClient("test.mp3")
                    .copyFromUrl(sourceBlob.getBlobUrl());
            System.out.println(res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob-from-url) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer that helped a lot. However, for some reason even being in the same storage account and using MSI I needed to add the sas token. So my finan solution looks smth like this:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     String sasToken = sourceBlobClient.generateSasToken();
copyBlobClient.copyFromUrl(sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl() + "?" + sasToken);

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using the Java SDK for Azure I solved it by copying the blob using the URL + the SAS token. Actually the resource you're getting through the URL won't appear as available if you don't have the right access to it. Here is the code I used to solve the problem:

```
BlobClient sourceBlobClient = blobServiceClient
                        .getBlobContainerClient(currentBucketName)
                        .getBlobClient(sourceKey);
// initializing the copy blob client
BlobClient copyBlobClient = blobServiceClient
        .getBlobContainerClient(newBucketName)
        .getBlobClient(newKey);
// Creating the SAS Token to get the permission to copy the source blob 
OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1);
BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true);
BlobServiceSasSignatureValues values = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, permission)
.setStartTime(OffsetDateTime.now());
String sasToken = sourceBlobClient.generateSas(values);

//Making the copy using the source blob URL + generating the copy 
var res = copyBlobClient.copyFromUrl(sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl() +"?"+ sasToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another way is to use the streaming API to download and upload data. In our company, we are not allowed to generate SAS token on our storage account due to security and we use the following to copy from an append blob to a block blob (overwriting):

```java
BlobAsyncClient src;
BlobAsyncClient dest;
//...
AppendBlobAsyncClient srcAppend = src.getAppendBlobAsyncClient();
Flux<ByteBuffer> streamData = srcAppend.downloadStream();
Mono<BlockBlobItem> uploaded = dest.upload(streamData, new ParallelTransferOptions(), true);
```

This returns `Mono<BlockBlobItem>` and you need to subscribe it to start the process. If used in a non-reactive context, perhaps the easiest way is to `block()`.

Note that this will only copy the data and additional work is needed if you also need to copy the metadata and tags. For tags, there is `BlobAsyncClientBase.getTags()`. For meta data, there is `BlobAsyncClientBase.getProperties()`. You can get these tags and metadata from the source and apply the same to dest