# Sync data between Blob storage accounts in the different regions using java SDK

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement where it is needed to sync data in Blob storage account across regions(Say between South-Central US region and West US region). [azcopy](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy) this is command line utility, can this be achieved using java SDK to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java SDK to copy data between storage accounts.

Please refer the sample code on how to copy data between storage accounts :

```
 try {
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                    .endpoint("https://<>.blob.core.windows.net/" )
                    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                    .buildClient();
            // get User Delegation Key
            OffsetDateTime delegationKeyStartTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
            OffsetDateTime delegationKeyExpiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(7);
            UserDelegationKey key =blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(delegationKeyStartTime,delegationKeyExpiryTime);

            BlobContainerClient sourceContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("test");
            BlobClient sourceBlob = sourceContainerClient.getBlobClient("test.mp3");
            // generate sas token
            OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1);
            BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true);

            BlobServiceSasSignatureValues myValues = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, permission)
                    .setStartTime(OffsetDateTime.now());
            String sas =sourceBlob.generateUserDelegationSas(myValues,key);

            // copy
            BlobServiceClient desServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                    .endpoint("https://<>.blob.core.windows.net/" )
                    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                    .buildClient();
            BlobContainerClient desContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("test");
            String res =desContainerClient.getBlobClient("test.mp3")
                    .copyFromUrl(sourceBlob.getBlobUrl()+"?"+sas);
            System.out.println(res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Also, you can use azcopy to sync the data between storage accounts and you can automate this process creating a bat file and running bat file as cron jobs or task scheduler

**Reference** :

[Copy Blob in Azure Blob Storage using Java v12 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946587/copy-blob-in-azure-blob-storage-using-java-v12-sdk)